# method to query for changes in single table with multiple data loads and set the mutationcode identifier

Tags: sql, delta

i'm looking for the best SQL server method to compare data in a table and mark the field mutation_code with code 01 if there are differences from the previous load.

as you can see there are differences in the table for eric and lucy so they have been marked with mutationcode 01. What would be the query needed to achieve this?

Table

```
loadno, firstname, lastname, street, streetno, mutationcode
load1, eric, smith, sophostreet, 42 
load1, mark, kras, downtownstreet, 10
load1, lucy, polka, newamsterdam, 466
load2, eric, smith, sophostreet, 43, 01
load2, mark, kras, townstreet, 10
load2, lucy, polka, newamsterdam, 466, 01
```

looking forward for your advice, best regards,

Comment: It seems your column headers don't match your data.  Is `load1`/`load2` an actual column in the data?  If so, what is its name?

Comment: ebyrob, your right, corrected it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following may work if your table only has two loadno values:

```
UPDATE r1
SET r1.mutationcode = 1
FROM record as r1
join record as r2 on r2.loadno < r1.loadno
                  and r2.firstname = r1.firstname
                  and r2.lastname = r1.lastname
WHERE r2.street != r1.street
   or r2.streetno != r1.streetno
   ;
```